# Eventlog removing specific name from user counter

Tags: c#, .net

Good morning. I'm still against this blocker, so I'm trying to ask again but this time more clear.

```
public string User { get; set; }
public int countUsers { get; set; }
public Users(int count, string name)
{
    countUsers = count;
    User = name;
}

public void getCountUsers()
{
    number = 0; //
    UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
    EventLog myNewLog = new EventLog(); 
    myNewLog.Log = "Security";
    foreach (EventLogEntry entry in myNewLog.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.InstanceId == 4624 && entry.TimeWritten.Date == DateTime.Today)
        {
            if (UserList.Count > 0)
            {
                bool check = false;
                foreach (var user in UserList)
                {
                    if (user.User == entry.ReplacementStrings[5])
                    {
                        user.countUsers += 1;
                        check = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!check)
                {
                    Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                    UserList.Add(u);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Users u = new Users(1, entry.ReplacementStrings[5]);
                UserList = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
                UserList.Add(u);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void amount()
{
    var totalUsers = UserList.Sum(user => user.countUsers);
    Console.WriteLine("There has been {0} users on {1}",
    totalUsers, DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
}

public void amountPer()
{
    foreach (var user in UserList.Where(u => u.User != "SYSTEM"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User  {0} has been online {1}x 
     times",user.User,user.countUsers);
    }

}
```

Is what I currently have. What I'm facing is, that I need to figure out how to filter out in amount just as I did in amountPer.

Yet, I don't want to use a for each loop because I need a general number.
[What it outputs currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkvbm.png)
That includes the name System, which I want to be filtered out so it only counts the actual users. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter only the NOT System users you could simply use Count with the lambda expression that exclude the SYSTEM user

```
public void amount()
{

    var totalUsers = UserList.Count(user => user.User != "SYSTEM");
    Console.WriteLine("There has been {0} users on {1}",
    totalUsers, DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
}
```

However this doesn't mean that your code doesn't loop. The loop is still there hidden by the Count extension

Comment: Holy hell, I've been trying to figure this out for such a long time now, not really great for someone that is quite new at C#. This will get me going, one more question though, if you have the time.

I want to use shown code above for other days aswell. So, for example: Datetime.Now.AddDays(-1) Would I need to make a getcountUser() method for every day?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5QrpxpZX is what I currently use to show the amount of users everyday. I already think this is too much :P

Comment: What you need to do is add a new property to the Users class containing the date you wish to check and then change your code to use this property in the comparison operation. You could even change the constructor to receive a third parameter and making it mandatory to use your class